# How to use DateTime diff : PHP

Tags: php, datetime, diff

I am using the DateTime diff function in a function, for this I need to work out the amount of seconds between a set of dates. I have this function:

```
public function CanBet($bettilltime, $bettilldate, $betsettime, $betsetdate, $amount) {
    $can_bet = true;
    $bettilltime = new DateTime(date("H:i:s", strtotime($bettilltime)));
    $bettilldate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($bettilldate)));

    $betsettime = new DateTime(date("H:i:s", strtotime("H:i:s", $betsettime)));
    $betsetdate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Y-m-d", $betsetdate)));

    $timeDiff = $betsettime->diff($bettilltime);
    return print $timeDiff->s;
    $dateDiff = $betsetdate->diff($bettilldate);
    return print $dateDiff->s;
    if ($this->GetUserBalance() > $amount) {
        if ($timeDiff->s >= 0) {
            if ($dateDiff->s >= 0) {
                $can_bet = true;
            }
            else {
                $can_bet = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            $can_bet = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        $can_bet = false;
    }

    return $can_bet = false;
}
```

I am returning the prints of the $....Diff to check if they are being to a value, however these always return 0. I have tried to use `->d | ->m  |->y | ->i | ->s | ->h | ->days` (I understand that these values do not return seconds, I used them to test) in order to get a value to print from these, however, it does not show a value other than 0, what am I doing wrong here?

***Note***
I have set the final return to false here to allow for me to be able to stop the function that uses this from working, I want to keep my values where they are.

Comment: Why are you even creating separate data and time objects for both bettill and betset?

Comment: @MarkBaker, I need to get a difference between the 2 separate values, as this is for a betting site I need to be able to check that the user is not betting after the "off" of the race/meeting. Also, as the races/meetings have separate times and dates, I need to be able to check each individually. This is at client request.

Comment: No, I mean why use `$bettilltime = new DateTime(date("H:i:s", strtotime("H:i:s", $bettilltime)));
    $bettilldate = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Y-m-d", $bettilldate)));` rather than create a single `$bettill = new DateTime($bettilldate.' '.$bettilltime);`

Comment: @MarkBaker, The client has asked for separate checks on the date and time to (apparently) reduce chance of discrepancies.

Comment: Note also that strtotime doesn't take any kind of format mask as an argument.... so those lines of code are invalid and won't return a valid date or time at all

Comment: Can't understand your clients logic..... it doesn't make sense

Comment: Visual Studios intellisense did tell me that, however on another question a (or what looked like) a senior programmer did it and I thought I was just being stupid by not

Comment: I have to agree, a single check would work better and I have suggested, however this is how they want it

Comment: But what's the meaning of two checks? What are you supposed to be checking against each?

Comment: I have to check to see if each of the date and time for the race/meeting is greater than the time of the bet being set

Comment: As it stands, with invalid date and time objects, none of it will work anyway

Comment: I have amended the code so that the date format is not in the `strtotime` and this still has not solved the issue I am having

Comment: A race takes place at a date/time..... a bet is placed at a date/time..... those are both fixed points..... you can't have the same date/time occur again (unless you're getting philosophical about cosmology) so a date/time is a unique combination.... there's no need for the second check unless you want to preclude punters from betting at the same time on different days

Comment: I understand fully where you are coming from, this is just how the client wants it

Comment: What format are the values of $bettilltime, $bettilldate, $betsettime, $betsetdate passed into the function? Are they strings like `'2015-05-13'` and `'10:45:30'`?

Comment: The come out of the database as `'2015-05-13'` and `'10:45:30'`

Comment: Then start by using `$bettilltime = new DateTime($bettilltime);
    $bettilldate = new DateTime($bettilldate);

    $betsettime = new DateTime($betsettime);
    $betsetdate = new DateTime($betsetdate);` instead of using middleman unix timestamps to reformat them to what they already were

Comment: As soon as I can get back onto the site, I will try this and let you know, the server has gone down -_-

Comment: @MarkBaker, this now returns a value greater than 0, my issue now is, what chack do I use? As I want to know if betsetdate/time is less than bettilldate/time, do I use `$timeDiff <= 0 /*or*/ $timediff >= 0`?

Comment: You do know that you can compare DateTime objects directly using standard comparison operator? You don't need to calculate the time difference

Comment: I have tired this and it didn't work for me

Comment: If you tried, then edit the question to show the code where you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just doing simple DateTime object comparisons, this should work (and also eliminates a lot of spurious `else` checks.

```
public function CanBet($bettilltime, $bettilldate, $betsettime, $betsetdate, $amount) {
    $can_bet = false;

    $bettilltime = new DateTime($bettilltime);
    $bettilldate = new DateTime($bettilldate);

    $betsettime = new DateTime($betsettime);
    $betsetdate = new DateTime($betsetdate); 

    if ($this->GetUserBalance() > $amount) {
        if ($betsettime <= $bettilltime) {
            if ($betsetdate <= $bettilldate) {
                $can_bet = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return $can_bet;
}
```

but

```
public function CanBet($bettilltime, $bettilldate, $betsettime, $betsetdate, $amount) {
    $can_bet = false;

    $bettilltime = new DateTime($bettilldate.' '.$bettilltime);
    $betsettime = new DateTime($betsetdate.' '.$betsettime);

    if ($this->GetUserBalance() > $amount) {
        $can_bet = $betsettime <= $bettilltime;
    }

    return $can_bet;
}
```

will return exactly the same results without that meaningless split of date and time

**EDIT**

Even simpler:

```
public function CanBet($bettilltime, $bettilldate, $betsettime, $betsetdate, $amount) {
    $bettilltime = new DateTime($bettilldate.' '.$bettilltime);
    $betsettime = new DateTime($betsetdate.' '.$betsettime);

    if ($this->GetUserBalance() > $amount) {
        return $betsettime <= $bettilltime;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Would ternery help here at all? (e.g. `$can_bet = ($betsettime <= $bettilltime) ? true : false;`)

Comment: And no, a ternary wouldn't make any difference besides making it less readable

Comment: The logic is absolutely perfect, I can see that it SHOULD work with no questions asked, however it seems not to...

Comment: [Demo](http://ideone.com/mAYgdt) to demonstrate that it does work; can't explain without debugging with the values that you're actually passing in

Comment: First port of call is probably to debug the arguments being passed in, to make sure that the date/time values are actually strings (and that $amount is less than the value returned by the `GetUserBalance()` call

Comment: Or double-check your PHP version: DateTime object comparison won't work with < 5.2.2

Comment: I believe I have found the issue... The bettill date and time are coming through as NULL, I did as you suggested (stupid of me not to think of var dumping) and got these results: `bettilltime: NULL  
bettilldate: NULL  
betsettime: string(10) "2015-05-13"  
betsetdate: string(8) "12:45:13" `

Comment: Hmmmm, yes.... nulls would cause a problem: issue with the caller? Or something you need to validate in this method?

Comment: It was me forgetting to put a hidden input in the form that contained the 2 values... My own stupid fault *slaps own face*

Comment: This is now working perfect, thank you very much for this and sorry that it was something so stupid that caused it, was a silly oversight on my part. Gracias Señor